# how to refresh or realtime image overlay using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, real-time

I am using Leaflet. and I have a project and it change the .HTML file connected with Leaflet.

my project overlays images using "addTo(map)" in HTML file and I want to follow them without F5 (refreshing)

How can I follow it in realtime?

sample overlay:

```
var map = L.map('image-map', {
        minZoom: 16,
        maxZoom: 18,
        }).setView([46.975768, 7.436308], 17);


var imageUrl = '../Bilder/Karten/Normalansicht.png',
    imageBounds = [[46.966635, 7.415942], [46.998849, 7.470108]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You dont provide enough information. Realtime wont be possible if you don't have a way to inform the client that the server has changed the html on server side. Look for something like websocket maybe

Comment: However, you can refresh the image at a given time interval, without refreshing the whole page

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#imageoverlay-seturl